# Are there 'constellations' in the Star Wars galaxy?

Tags: star-wars

Are there any classically named constellations from any of the folks inhabiting the galaxy far, far away?  This is a species or group that name visible objects in their cosmos symbols when 'connecting the dots'.  These can be taken very lightly like most of us do with traditional Western constellations here on Earth, or can have meaning.

I considered that maybe in the future "Luke's Map" might have some lore attached to it, but other than that, **are there any constellations in Star Wars?**

Comment: Ahem; http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Constellations

Comment: Each planet that developed life likely has their own set of constellations. Since the position of the stars will be different on different planets, it isn't possible to have constellations common to all of them.

Comment: @Seeds - that's okay by me - it is not a conflict if it is different constellations from different planetary systems and species.  Just some illustrative meaning or naming convention or whatever, within stories and mythology.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Yes

Constellations are mentioned in *Ezra’s Duel with Danger*, a Disney canon tie-in to *Star Wars: Rebels*.

> Ezra entered a cavern so massive it had its own night sky, sparkling
> with constellations he didn’t recognize. One resembled a round face
> with long, pointy ears.
>
> <sub>*Ezra’s Duel with Danger*</sub>

This implies, of course, that there are constellations he *does* recognize, although the names are not given.

Comment: To clarify, these are actual stars?  (Sorry, I have not seen anything other than the movies)  But I get that the implication is, yes, there are constellations elsewhere.

Comment: @Mikey - It’s more of a vision, I think. What’s relevant is that Ezra has seen constellations before.

Comment: I'd be curious to see if anyone can find some concrete names.  Still, +1

Comment: @Mikey The constellations would be unique on each planet, because constellations are a matter of perspective. Star Wars tends to do a lot of planet hoping, so any particular focus on constellations of a single world is unlikely.